# Unity under Ubuntu 11.04 in VMware Workstation

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 32bit as virtual machine in VMware Workstation under a 64 bit Windows7 host system. The surface of Ubuntu is Gnome, after I got a message, that Unity needs some 3D graphics...

Now I shut down my VM and enable the checkbox "Accelerate 3d Graphics" and started again. The VMware tools are also installed in the virtual machine.

Furthermore I tried [the following suggestion](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html). 
It didn't work either.

Comment: Ask this on the sister-site, askubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

VMWare won't let you use 3D graphics acceleration on non-Windows VM's as Bisti mentioned.  What you **can** do is install the 2D version of Unity:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-2d-default-settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Accelerate 3d Graphics is for Windows VMs only. As far as i know, you can not launch Ubuntu Unity or desktop effects on Workstation for now.

Comment: Not true. I am running Unity in a VMWare Workstation installation.

Comment: @Kyle - Would you care to explain how? That is, after all, what this question is about. You would certainly get my +1 if you could actually answer the question.

Comment: Wish I could tell you. I just got the same error message as you, then turned on Accelerate 3d Graphics after rebooting the machine. Works perfectly fine now. I have a GeForce 8800GT, if it matters any (I doubt it).

Answer (score 1):

The suggested fix you referenced from  http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html worked for me using VMWare Player.  However...  I had to extend the sleep timeout to "30".  This timing value is likely hardware dependant so play around until you find the value that works for you.

```
Exec=bash -c "sleep 30; /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon"
```